# seed-job fails fails to parse build user vars plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the below code in my Jenkins job (pipeline script):

```
def user_id = ''
wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
    addBadge text: env.BUILD_USER + ', ' + params.Computer
    user_id = env.BUILD_USER_ID.toLowerCase()
}
```

But the code fails in the seed-job with:

```
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslException: startup failed:
script: 106: unexpected token: class
       wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
              ^

1 error
```

I've found this [suggestion](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1921/18007) but then groovy syntax throws error of: `unexpected char : '\'`

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to warp the entire script code in single quotes instead double quotes (in `myjob.jobdsl` file):

```
definition {
 cps {
  script('''
   def user_id = ''
   wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
      addBadge text: env.BUILD_USER + ', ' + params.Computer
      user_id = env.BUILD_USER_ID.toLowerCase()
   }
  ''')
 }
}
```